# Using Bootstrap with Bcrypt sessions form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bcrypt

I'm using Bcrypt and has_secure_password for user authentications in a basic Rails app. For all of my other forms in the app I'm using the gem bootstrap_form which enables me to have nice looking bootstrap forms rather than the ugly default ones.

The problem is that Bcrypt doesn't seem to allow this for the sessions login form. It would be really good if I were able to integrate Bootstrap into this login form so that I don't need to play around with css for a long time.

My sessions/new.erb looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
<h3>Log In</h3>
<div class="form-group">
 <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: 'Email', 
 :class => 'class_name' %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password], placeholder: 
 'password', :class => 'class_name' %><br>
 <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_path %>
</div><br>
<div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log In" %></div>
<% end %>
```

And my sessions controller looks like this:

```
def create
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
 session[:user_id] = user.id
 redirect_to new_comment_path, notice: "Logged in!"
 else
  flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
 render "new"
end
end

def destroy
 session[:user_id] = nil
 redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
end
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: what do you mean by "Bcrypt doesn't seem to allow this for the sessions login form"?

Comment: What error do you have? It's more likely to be an issue in your controller as this is where Bcrypt is activated.

Comment: it looks fine, what exactly errors you are facing ?

Comment: All of the above code is fine, but if I change the form_tag to a bootstrap_form_tag then there will be a 'type error in welcome#index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gem Documentation [LINK](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms)

But you'r probably doing

`<%= bootstrap_form_tag sessions_path do %>`,

instead of

`<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: sessions_path do |f| %>`

**Answer:** Try like this

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: sessions_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit "Log In" %>
<% end %>
```